# Disable collapsing of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-widget, expandablelistview

The default behavior of `ExpandableListView` is to collapse a group when its header is clicked.  Is it possible to prevent this from happening?

I've tried:

- Setting `OnTouchListener` on the list.  This interferes with scrolling.
- Setting an `OnGroupClickListener` on the list (in `onCreate()`).  This works for all clicks *after* the first.

Has anyone else accomplished this?  Why might the `OnGroupClickListener` miss the first click?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: This worked for me -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464599.

Comment: While helpful, that thread does not answer my stated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem had to do with there being both a focusable element in the group header and an `OnGroupClickListener` set.  Removing the listener solved my problem.

Comment: didn't solve it for me (I hadn't even set one in the first place). I have clickable elements *inside* the header, but the header itself should not be clickable.

Comment: OnGroupClickListener(null);

Answer (score 32):

You can ignore click on group items like this:

```
mMyExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
      // Doing nothing
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

Maybe It`s too late,I use onGroupCollapseListener in the activity and implement onGroupCollapse Method.(expandView is ExpandableListView)

```
@Override
public void onGroupCollapse(int collapseIndex) {
    expandView.expandGroup(collapseIndex);
}
```

Comment: I think this should not be implemented! Andrus way is better!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code on the item for which you want to disable clicking on:
`{convertView.setClickable(false);}`

Comment: perfect code if you want to disable click on the particular condition