# ExpandableListView - Is conditional expansion possible?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView bound to a SQLite database. To simplify things, lets assume the database contains two columns: `title` and `body`. In the ExpandableListView, there is a `group` for each `title`, and a `child`for each corresponding `body`.

Now to make things more interesting, some of the rows in the SQLite database do not have a `body` (that is... they only have a `title`). As you can see, if there is no body, then there is no reason to expand the group... because the child will be empty (i.e. String `body == ""`).

I'm searching for a way to catch a situation like this, and skip the group's expansion. I don't want a blank child to be expanded. To put it in psuedo code, I want something like this:

```
if (body.getText() == "") {
  //DO NOT EXPAND
  //DO OTHER STUFF
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trick is in the OnGroupClickListener. The following code shoud work. Put at the end of your onCreate method for the ExpandableListActivity.

```
lv.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
      int groupPosition, long id) {

    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchRow(id); //Get Title & body from SQLite table
    if (c.getString(Constants.bodyColumn).equals("")) {
      //If the body returned from SQLite is empty, return true
      return true; //True means the click HAS been handled.
    }
    return false; //Click has not been handled, so let Android expand here.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a very simple and easy manner

```
expListView.setEnabled(false);
```

whenever you want to disable it, and then when your task, for which you are waiting for is complete then you can call

```
expListView.setEnabled(true);
```