# Android: Nested List Views and item heights

Tags: android, listview, nested

I am currently trying to create a nested ListView.

An outer ListView contains items, of which each consists of a TextView, as caption, and another ListView with children.

Filling the ListViews works really nice using another nested ListView adapter, yet, when it comes to actually displaying the content on the device, the nested list items are not high enough to display all the children. To be exact, only the first nested list item is displayed.

My current layout approach is the following:

Outer list item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="5px"
        >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/day"
              android:textSize="14sp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="#ff5e00"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>


    <ListView android:id="@+id/innerList"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:fadingEdge="none"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

and an inner list layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="5px"
        >

    <TextView  android:id="@+id/innertextview"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:scrollHorizontally="false"
               android:singleLine="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Is there any chance to adapt the size of the outer list item in a way that all the inner list items will be displayed?

I also looked at ExpandableListViews. This approach worked, yet, I do not want to have the list items collapsed.

Thank you very much,
Matthias

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not really like this solution, so I looked into this issue some more and found another solution:

ExpandableListView inherits from ListView. What it does is overriding the getView method from BaseAdapter and make a distinction between child and parent items. It is not a real nested list, but it flattens the list by using different layout items.

The same can be done for creating a NestedListView. Inherit from ListView and expect a self created adapter, which makes a distinction between child and parent layout items.
For each one return the appropriately filled layout items.

Done.

Comment: How did you do that? You created a class that gets the multiple listviews with their children and did what with them?

Comment: Not multiple. Only one with different view layouts. See https://github.com/klassm/andFHEM/blob/master/app/src/li/klass/fhem/widget/NestedListView.java for the widget I created.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make the items in an ExpandableListView uncollaposable. This is probably you best option. For instructions on how disable collapsing, checkout this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462265/disable-collapsing-of-expandablelistview).